# If $P=\prod (X-x_i)\in\mathbb R[X]$ and $Q\in \mathbb R[X]$ with coefficients close enough to those of $P$ then $Q = \prod (X-y_i)$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $P = X^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_kX^k \in \mathbb R[X]$ such that $P = \prod (X-x_i)$ with $x_i$ all distinct and $Q = X^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_kX^k \in \mathbb R[X]$,

Show that if $b_i$ are close enough to $a_i$ then $Q = \prod(X-y_i)$ with $y_i$ all distinct.

I think I need to prove that :

$\forall i\in[0,n-1],\exists \delta_i >0,(b_0,\cdots,b_{n-1})\in B(a_0,\delta_0)\times\cdots\times B(a_{n-1},\delta_{n-1})$ then $Q=\prod(X-y_i)$ with $y_i$ all distinct.

When trying to prove it, I found that it can be simplified to :

$\exists \delta>0,(b_0,\cdots,b_{n-1})\in B((a_0,\cdots ,a_{n-1}),\delta)\implies Q=\prod(X-y_i)$ with $y_i$ all distinct.

Though I have attempted to prove a lot of times. Anyone has an answer ?

Comment: Do you suppose $x_i\in\Bbb R$ and want $y_i\in\Bbb R,$ or don't you mind if they  only belong to  $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @AnneBauval I honestly don't know for sure. I suppose it is in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is up to you, but see comments below David Lui's answer.

Comment: I think you should edit your post to clarify this. And since you already got an answer, the honest way would probably be to stick to it in your question (i.e. don't require the $y_i$'s to be real), and ask a new question in a new post  if you want to solve the same problem but with real $x_i$'s *and* $y_i$'s. (I am not able to solve it.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Okay I think I'll do that thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discriminant is a continuous function of the coefficients, and it's zero iff the polynomial has a multiple root. By continuity, if $p$ doesn't have a multiple root then $disc(p) \neq 0$, then there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that if the coefficients of $q$ are within $\epsilon$ of $p$ then $disc(q) \neq 0$, so $q$ doesn't have a multiple root.

Comment: I only know the discriminant in the case $n=2$. Even if your proof is correct, I can't understand the notion at $n>2$. Though , thank you for your help !

Comment: Jotadiolyne Dicci, you can at least  check this solution in the case $n=2.$ David Lui, I don't think that for $n>2,$ if the $x_i$'s are real this method will give real $y_i$'s. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, it isn't that difficult for $n=2$ with the discriminant method.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't know, but there is no indication in the question that the roots had to be real too. Only that $p$ and $q$ have real coefficients.